# Nested Loops with Multiple Conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a loop that pulls conditions from a specific cells from another worksheet. The condition works great on its own but when I include the other conditions for the same data set it somehow marks all the cells as incorrect. Below is what I wrote:

```
rate_check = False
    Do While sh_controls.Cells(j, 10) <> vbNullString
    If sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) <= sh_controls.Range("c2") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 10) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Best Efforts" Then
        rate_check = True
    ElseIf sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) >= sh_controls.Range("c2") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 10) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Mandatory" Then
        rate_check = True
    ElseIf sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) <= sh_controls.Range("c3") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 10) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Mandatory" Then
       rate_check = True
    ElseIf sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) >= sh_controls.Range("c3") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 10) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Best Efforts" Then
       rate_check = True
    End If

 If sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) >= sh_controls.Range("e2") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 11) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Best Efforts" Then
       rate_check = True
    ElseIf sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) <= sh_controls.Range("e2") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 11) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Mandatory" Then
       rate_check = True
    ElseIf sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) >= sh_controls.Range("e3") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 11) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Mandatory" Then
       rate_check = True
    ElseIf sh_audit.Cells(i, 4) <= sh_controls.Range("e3") And sh_controls.Cells(j, 11) = sh_audit.Cells(i, 8) And sh_audit.Cells(i, 9) = "Best Efforts" Then
       rate_check = True
    End If
```

It seems to be overlapping the conditions on the same data set...any ideas!!!???

Comment: It would help if you pasted into the question some screenshots of your data, and also if you gave us a bit more of your code - e.g. how are `i` and `j` being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

With that logic, if the first set of condition evaluate to `True`, then the second set is pointless. You can use two results and combine them at the end:

```
rate_check = False
Do While ...
    check1 = False
    If ...
      check1 = True
    End If

    check2 = False
    If ...
      check2 = True
    End If

    rate_check = check1 And check2
Loop
```